# Aplicação específica do atributo [ChildActionOnly]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Vi pela documentação do ASP.NET MVC que o uso do atributo `[ChildActionOnly]` impede que o método seja chamado diretamente via GET, apenas através de uma view específica. Francamente, não entendi. Alguém pode esclarecer?

Exemplo de utilização:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Resultado()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retirei da documentação esse trecho aqui:

> Qualquer método marcado com `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` poderá ser
>   chamado apenas através de `Action` ou `RenderAction` HTML extensions
>   methods.

Ou seja, se você possuir um conteúdo que deve obrigatoriamente fazer parte de uma View principal, normalmente `PartialViews`.

### Em que cenários isso poderia ser útil?

Por exemplo ao montar um template onde algumas partes do seu site são dividas em `PartialViews`, como _top.cshtml, _bottom.cshtml com actions `Top()` e `Bottom()` talvez seja interessante evitar que sejam exibidos diretamente no browser a partir da url: `site.com.br/home/top`

Comment: obrigado pela participação, @iuristona!